# how to maintain 8 week partition datas and removing other partitions

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

I have a pl/sql application which runs every week.  It creates a partition(e.g. `2013W2`8) and load data to the newly created partition.

My requirement is that I have to maintain eight week partitions in a rolling window, so that every week after the run is completed the table still has only eight current week partitions.

Can any one suggest how to drop the other week partition?

Comment: show us what have you tried so far and where exactly you are having the issue ... kindly refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: you need to write a package or upgrade to 11g.

Comment: http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/oracle/implement-rolling-partition-using-interval-partition-11g/ is the same for interval partition. Try tow tweak it for your needs. I did the same a few years ago, for range partition, searching for the proc, if I get that I will post

Comment: So you have to drop any partitions other than the most recent 8.

Comment: yes i want current week and previous 7 week partition data